# many to many database architecture

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am new with databases , i am just stuck with many to many data relations in my database. for example 
I have an array of activities with primary key as Activity_Id , and a single activity can have multiple sessions as it is a one to many relation ,

but  further a session can also have multiple venues and a venue can be used in multiple sessions, its a many to many relation between sessions and venues , 
How could I separate venues of a certain sessions and sessions for a venue to send as a response on an APi ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: By creating a reference table

Comment: @Cid Can you elaborate please ?
with given example

Comment: In an RDBMS, there is no 'many-to-many'. There is only 'one-to-many'. So recipes --> recipe_ingredient <-- ingredients

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say you have:

```
session_table: id, name
venue_table: id, name
```

Now, in order to have many to many relationship between those tables you would need to create a third pivot table:

```
session_venue_table: session_table_id, venue_table_id
```

Then, to get sessions from a venue you'll do:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM session_table s
WHERE s.id in (
    SELECT pivot.session_table_id as id 
    FROM session_venue_table pivot
    WHERE pivot.venue_id = 'selectedVenueId'
)
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Good - but you wouldn't do that. You would normally use a join.

Comment: Sure, I was just trying to keep it simple.

Comment: JOINs are simple.

Comment: Yes, everything is simple once you get it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your tables have this structure.

Activity :

```
Activity_Id | SomeActivityData
------------+-----------------
 1          | blabla
 2          | example
 3          | some things
 4          | nice data
```

Venue :

```
Venue_Id    | SomeVenueData
------------+--------------
 1          | hello
 2          | another example
 3          | anything
 4          | cool data
```

An Activity has 1 or more (n) Venue and a Venue has 1 or more (n) Activity.

This means the relations can be represented this way :

> [Activity] (1,n) -> (Relation between activity and venue) <- (1,n) [Venue]

You could build a third table for referencing ids in relations

ActivityVenue :

```
Activity_Id | Venue_Id
------------+---------
```

The primary key of the table ActivityVenue is the **combination** of both **foreign keys** from tables `Activity` and Venue

Let's say the Activities 1 and 3 belongs to Venue 1, the venues 2 and 3 belongs to activity 2 and the activity 4 and venue 4 are in relation.

The table ActivityVenue will looks like this :

```
Activity_Id | Venue_Id
------------+---------
 1          | 1
 3          | 1
 2          | 2
 2          | 3
 4          | 4
```

There won't be duplications of keys if you set properly constraints.

EDIT :

I **strongly** suggest you to take a look at Merise method